# How to add navigation property in the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I was trying to add a new repository class for a table called `PersonFieldGroupDomain` however this is how it looks like:

[image]

So basically we have only two fields for this table. So I went to Entity Framework model designer and I couldn't add this table to the designer using Update Model from Database, it is not even visible. However when I see the other tables which have dependency on it, I can see it only as Navigational Property.

So, I need to add a new record to it but since I cannot reach it from the context directly like I do for others, I tried adding it using "Attach" method like this:

```
var fieldGroupSet = FieldGroupSets.Single(t=>t.FieldGroupSetId == 1);
fieldGroupSet.PersonFieldGroupDomainReference.Attach(Domains.Single(t=>t.DomainId == 2));
```

and this code didn't work. At least I tested it on LinqPad using the same context assembly I am using in the actual project.

This article seems talking about some of the ways I can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx but none of them seemed working for me.

Any working idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the DomainId primary key? You need to have a primary key in the table before entity model picks it up from database.

Comment: Yes, `DomainId` is a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this table is just a join table.  EF will hide these in the designer view.  Notice if you add a surrogate key or anything to the table, you'll start seeing it in the designer as an entity.

To use it, it should be as simple as

```
var fieldGroupSet = FieldGroupSets.Single(t => t.FieldGroupSetId == 1);
var domain = Domains.Single(t => t.DomainId == 2);
fieldGroupSet.Domain = domain;
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Edited by OP:**

***My Note:*** I am sorry editing your answer, but in order to mark it as an answer, I need to put the actual code I used which worked that follows your logic:

```
var fieldGroupSet = FieldGroupSets.Single(t=>t.FieldGroupSetId == 1);
var domain = Domains.Single(t => t.DomainId == 3);
fieldGroupSet.PersonFieldGroupDomain = domain;
SaveChanges();
```

In the code above, since the PersonFieldGroupDomain is a navigation property, it directly goes to `Domain` so it is type of `Domain` when you reach it with `fieldGroupSet.PersonFieldGroupDomain` property. As seen in the code above, I am directly setting it with an existing `Domain` object and after saving the changes, the changes become persistent in the database and it worked!